# Linking css built in eclipse to jsp and getting results

Tags: css, eclipse, jsp

I am trying to link a css i created in eclipse to the jsp and when i run the project i get no results in my browser. I've tried it in multiple ways, by putting

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/first.css" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="boe/WebContent/first.css" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="(my full path to the file)" type="text/css">
```

I've tried so much that i don't remember how i got it to not error out. i am getting this

```
Tag (link) should be an empty-element tag.
```

as the caution error.

i can not find any step by steps on creating the css and making it link to the jsp, so it can show up in my browser.

here is my code for both the jsp and the css.

jsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/first.css" type="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>TestPage - Test1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-container">Hello World</div>
    <%Date d = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());%>
    this page was last viewed <%= d.toString() %>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#page-container {
    width: 760px;
    margin: auto;
    background: red;
}
```

any help on finding a step by step or if you have a good explanation, it would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Tag (link) should be an empty-element tag.

This error message is telling you that your `link` tag needs a closing slash:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/first.css" type="text/css" /> <-- see the closing '/'
```

If that doesn't fix it, my guess is that your path is not quite right.

Comment: Thank you for that. it took the error away, but still am getting no results for the css implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I changed in the

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/first.css" type="text/css">
```

to

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <%@include file="css/first.css" %></style>
</head>
```

and in my eclipse project explorer under the "WebContent" file i added a folder named "CSS" and moved first.css to that folder.

Although from what i read, this is a very inefficient way of linking it because it imports the entire css.

Comment: Don't you need the entire CSS? This would actually be more performant because it reduces the number of requests required to load the page and its resources.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code replace 'css' with the full path of the css file
u can get the full path by right click on .css file -> properties->location
copy that and paste in above code in place of 'css'